# Override community extension controller is not working in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am using Quote2Sales community extension, but i need some customization in it so i am overriding controller by local module.

In Community folder Bobcares package and in this Quote2Sales extension.

To override RequestController.php i have made Mt package inside local and in it Quote2Sales folder. In it controllers and make file RequestController.php . In RequestController.php code is as following:

```
require_once 'Bobcares/Quote2Sales/controllers/RequestController.php';

class Mt_Quote2Sales_RequestController extends Bobcares_Quote2Sales_RequestController {
---
---
}
```

And in etc folder config.xml file code is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mt_Quote2Sales>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mt_Quote2Sales>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quote2sales>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mt_quote2sales before="Bobcares_Quote2Sales">Mt_Quote2Sales</mt_quote2sales>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </quote2sales>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <quote2sales>
                <class>Mt_Quote2Sales_Helper</class>
            </quote2sales>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

And also add code in Mt_Quote2Sales.xml as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mt_Quote2Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Bobcares_Quote2Sales/>
            </depends>
        </Mt_Quote2Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But it is not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You should ensure that you have your module registration XML in `app/etc/modules/Mt_Quote2Sales.xml`, which should tell Magento that your module exists and is on the local code pool.

Second, you should tell Magento in that file that it should depend on your community module. This will immediately help by ensuring that it is loaded after the community module (which makes sense, because you're extending it). An example of this XML file might be:

```
# File: app/etc/modules/Mt_Quote2Sales.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mt_Quote2Sales>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Bobcares_Quote2Sales />
            </depends>
        </Mt_Quote2Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Third, as the others have mentioned already, remove the `community` component from your require path - include paths are not code pool specific, essential when extending controllers, which don't follow the autoloader's convention:

```
require_once 'Bobcares/Quote2Sales/controllers/RequestController.php';

class Mt_Quote2Sales_RequestController extends Bobcares_Quote2Sales_RequestController
{

}
```

Lastly, if it is still not working, you should create a simple frontAction which dumps out something and load it in the browser. If your XML is configured correctly, you might have a conflict with another module.

Make sure you clear or disable your cache.

## Edit

I've just seen that you've posted your attempt to rewrite a helper - unlike the controller configuration where you can just tell Magento that your controller should be loaded before the one you're extending, with models/helpers/blocks you need to *rewrite* the path for it:

```
# File: app/code/local/Mt/Quote2Sales/etc/config.xml
...
<global>
    <helpers>
        <quote2sales>
            <rewrite>
                <data>Mt_Quote2Sales_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </quote2sales>
    </helpers>
</global>
...
```

You can test this using `magerun` (if you have it), or with a simple ad hoc script like so:

```
# File ./test.php
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$test = Mage::helper('quote2sales');
var_dump(get_class($test)); // Mt_Quote2Sales_Helper_Data if you're configured correctly
```

Comment: I have changed my code as above but nothing is working..Can't override helper also.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Yes..currently cache is disabled... and i had cleared it many times.

Comment: Please check for the existence and format of your `app/etc/modules/Mt_Quote2Sales/.xml` file

Comment: In Mt_Quote2Sales.xml all thing is correct, still not working. And i am overriding Request.php file from Helper it is also not working.

Comment: Your module is called `Quote2Sales` not `Quote` - if you have the configuration set up properly it might be because of the `2` - you could try changing it to `QuoteToSales` instead

Comment: Hi..robbie i have changed my module to Quote.i have follow all steps said by you. In test php for controller i am getting result as
["quote2sales"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Mt_Quote"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "Bobcares_Quote2Sales"
  }
  ["moneybookers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "Phoenix_Moneybookers"
  }
and for helper 
string(20) "Mt_Quote_Helper_Data" 
but i am not understanding what is issue and why not overriding files from local.Please help me.

Comment: Hi again @ChandreshVora - I suggest you rename your module and all classes inside it to `QuoteToSales` to remove the number 2

Comment: I have changed module to Quote and all classes also.

Comment: please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

in your RequestController.php controller file your require once will come like this

```
require_once 'Bobcares/Quote2Sales/controllers/RequestController.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `require_once` is looking a bit funky. There is no need to specify `community` I believe.

The magento way:

```
if (!class_exists('Bobcares_Quote2Sales_RequestController', false)) {
    require_once Mage::getConfig()->getModuleDir('controllers', 'Bobcares_Quote2Sales') . '/RequestController.php';
}
```

Edit: Read the comments below for why you should absolutely make sure to add the second `false` parameter to the `class_exists` call

Comment: Don't use `class_exists` in Magento, it triggers the autoloader which throws an error if it does not find the class file. Instead, use `Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Bobcares_Quote2Sales')`

Comment: Cool thanks, I use this all the time in my development without issue. Probably something custom in the autoloader which deals with this.

Comment: Do you look at your `system.log` from time to time? ;)

Comment: Haha yep. I've even overridden the `mageCoreErrorHandler` to `die` instead of `Mage::log` :|

Comment: OK then either it's a customized autoloader or all classes actually exist that you are checking for. The default autoloader does not check if the file exists and returns false as it should, but instead includes it without checking and let the actual location be determined by include path.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I work in a heavily customised Magento world. I need to delve into the community edition more often.

Comment: @fschmengler the `false` second parameter stops the autoloader from kicking in when asking if the class exists

Comment: Right, I totally overlooked the parameter, sorry!

Comment: Possibly not my heavily customised instance then ;)